# Why is my doGet(e) function returning a null value even though i passed a parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

*This is my first time posting in stack overflow, i would appreciate it also if you would give feedback on how to post questions properly*

I am currently following this tutorial by "Learn Google Spreadsheets": [Tutorial that i am following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRQvySxaCW0&t=9s)

I copied this function to test if a parameter will be passed back to the server-side script (Code.gs)

```
**Code.gs**
    function doGet(e) {
     Logger.log(e);
     return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page');
    }
```

I have also created a basic html file (page.html) that would be rendered once the project is deployed.

After deploying/publishing the project as a web application I added a parameter at the link 
[published link with added name parameters at the end](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx5R6rgBZRbwPz-7ibocSLT0P5aKO83RO6WcSj5XZqjNqu1p_XP/exec?name=hans) however after running the doGet function the log viewer is displaying null

[Log Viwer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJtpB.png)

Answer (score 0):

### `e` is an **argument** representing an event parameter

To retrieve the parameter itself, you need to specify it - given that several [request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters) can be obtained through a `GET` request.

Also, you need to spevidy the `key` of a paramter in order to retrieve the corresponding `value`.

In your case, you are interested in `e.parameter` and more specifically in `e.parameter.name`.

So:

```
    function doGet(e) {
     Logger.log(e.parameter.name);
     return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page');
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering.I tried adding the ones you've pointed out however it prompts an error saying that - TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameter' of undefined (line 2, file "Configuration") - It looks like my project does not detect something... I don't know if I missed some setup but i followed the exact same steps from the tutorial that i am watching.

Comment: Did you try to run the code manually? This will not work with an `e.parameter` since it is undefined until you pass it to the URL of a WebApp. Instead,  justopen the `published link with added name parameters at the end` in the address line of the browser and then go to the script ediotr and to `View->Logs` WITHOUT running the script.

Comment: Hi, I tried adding the parameters in the published link and then entered... reloading the published link with the parameters, I viewed the logs and received the same error but the format has changed to this [20-04-13 20:54:56:819 HKT] TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameter' of undefined
    at doGet(Code:2:16)

Comment: Go to `View -> Executions` and click on the latest execution - you will see your logs there.